# cli::cli_warn() - getting a bulleted list in the output

Tags: r, command-line-interface, warnings

I've got a scenario where I'd like to format the output of a warning message using the `cli` package and need it to be able to print a bulleted list of warnings of variable length. If the length is known ahead of time, I can just supply the bullets explicitly, but I've been struggling to figure out how to apply bullets when the length isn't known ahead of time. Any help would be appreciated!

```r
beep_boop <- function(msg) {
  
  if (class(msg) != "character") cli::cli_warn(c("Oh no!", "x" = letters[1:3]))
  tibble::as_tibble(mtcars)
  
}

# this doesn't work as expected :(
beep_boop(3)
#> Warning: Oh no!
#> a
#> b
#> c
#> # A tibble: 32 × 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # … with 22 more rows
#> # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows

# what I'd like to see:
cli::cli_warn(c("Oh no!", 
                "x" = letters[1],
                "x" = letters[2],
                "x" = letters[3]))
#> Warning: Oh no!
#> ✖ a
#> ✖ b
#> ✖ c
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I should note --- in the console, the warning from `beep_boop()` prints beneath the tibble as expected & printing above the tibble is just how `reprex:::reprex()` formats it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the same shape of the vector. The desired vector has multiple elements with the same name. A more direct translation would be

```
beep_boop <- function(msg) {
  
  if (class(msg) != "character") cli::cli_warn(c("Oh no!", setNames(letters[1:msg], rep("x",msg))))
  tibble::as_tibble(mtcars)
}
```

Here I used `msg` as the number of items in the list to show. You just need to give them all the name `x=` which is done here with `setNames`